# Count occurences of list items in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list of words. Now I want to count how often all words in the list occur in each cell of a dataframe.

| text |
| --- |
| this is a test sentence |
| another sentence |

list = ["this", "test", "break"]

Result:

| text | occurence_count |
| --- | --- |
| this is a test sentence | 2 |
| another sentence | 0 |

My code does not work:

```
df["occurence_count"] = [df["text"].count(x) for x in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do this:

```py
a = ['this', 'test', 'break']  # 'list' shouldn't be used as a variable name

df['occurence_count'] = (
    df['text'].str.split().explode()
    .isin(set(a)).groupby(level=0).sum()
)
>>> df
                      text  occurence_count
0  this is a test sentence                2
1         another sentence                0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
import re
l = ['this', 'test', 'break']
s = set(l)
df['occurence_count'] =df['text'].apply(
            lambda x:len(set(re.split('\s+',x)).intersection(s)))
```

So you split them into words, get a set and look for an intersection in your list and get len

(BTW don't use `list` as variable name, its a keyword in python)

output:

```
                      text  occurence_count
0  this is a test sentence                2
1         another sentence                0
```